# Using xcopy in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, xcopy

This is a follow-up to my previous questions ([Copy Update Create VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238165/) and [File Folder copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253965/)). So far I have the following script to copy files using *xcopy*:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strUserName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%")

' Discover Current Drive Path
curDrv = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) 'Drive Path
' USB Drive  and folder Path
upath = curdrv & "\ACG" 

' Source
avg8 = "c:\Docume~1\alluse~1\applic~1\avg8\update\download\*.*"
avg9 = "c:\Docume~1\alluse~1\applic~1\avg9\update\download\*.*"

If struserName = DARIO Then 
  '(1) GOTO Update
End If

If Not objFSO.FolderExists (upath) Then
  objFSO.CreateFolder (upath)
End If

If objFSO.FolderExists (avg9) Then
  'WshShell.Run "xcopy c:\Docume~1\alluse~1\applic~1\avg9\update\download\*.* usbdrive:\acg /D", , True
  '(2) WshShell.Run "xcopy avg9 upath /D", , True
  WshShell.Run "xcopy " & avg9 & " " & upath & " /D", , True
End If

If objFSO.FolderExists (avg8) Then
  'WshShell.Run "xcopy c:\Docume~1\alluse~1\applic~1\avg8\update\download\*.* &    usbdrive:\acg & /D", , True
  '(3) WshShell.Run "xcopy avg8 upath /D", , True
  WshShell.Run "xcopy " & avg8 & " " & upath & " /D", , True
End if

MsgBox "Definition Files Copied to your USB Drive @ " & upath, vbInformation, "Copy   Success..."
WScript.Quit

' Update 
If Not objFSO.FolderExists("C:\Updates") Then
  objFSO.CreateFolder "C:\Updates"
End If

If objFSO.FolderExists (upath) then
  Wshshell.Run "xcopy " & upath  & " " & "C:\Updates /D", , True '(4)
  MsgBox "Update Files Copied to C:\Updates" , vbInformation, "Copy Destination"
End IF

' Process
Message = "Click OK to Start Updating product." & vbCr & vbCr
Message = Message & "Click Cancel or (Esc) to Exit." &vbCr & vbCr
Message = Message & "Keep Selecting OK until you get" & vbCr
Message = Message & "the Message :-" & vbCr & vbCr
Message = Message & "''No New Update Files Available''" & vbCR & vbCR
X = MsgBox(Message, vbOKCancel, "AVG Update Module")

Select Case X
  Case vbCancel 
    MsgBox (strUserName & " cancelled the process.") , vbCritical, "Operation Terminated."
    Wscript.Quit

  Case vbOK
    If objFSO.FileExists("C:\Program Files\AVG\AVG89\avgupd.exe") Then
      WshShell.Run "C:\Program Files\AVG\AVG9\avgupd.exe" /source=folder /path="C:\Updates"
    End If

    If objFSO.FileExists("C:\Program Files\AVG\AVG8\avgupd.exe") Then
      WshShell.Run "C:\Program Files\AVG\AVG8\avgupd.exe" /source=folder /path="C:\Updates"
      '(5) Loop to Process
    End If
End Select
```

Unfortunately, xcopy doesn't take place. Could someone explain me what's wrong with the script and point me in the right direction to achieve points (1) - (5)? Thanks.

Comment: Why use xcopy and not the FileSystemObjects copy methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of xcopy use FileSystemObject.CopyFile like this.

```
If objFSO.FolderExists (avg9) Then
  objFSO.CopyFile "c:\Docume~1\alluse~1\applic~1\avg9\update\download\*.*", "usbdrive:\acg", True
End If
```

also use If Else rather than GOTO

```
If struserName = "DARIO" Then
    'Do whatever should be done if the user is DARIO
Else
    'Do whatever should be done if the user is not DARIO
End If
```

You could also use a subroutine or function like this

```
if struserName = "DARIO" Then
    DoDARIOStuff
else
   DoOtherStuff
end if
```

Then define the subroutines somewhere else in the code like this

```
Sub DoDARIOStuff
    'Do whatever should be done if the user is DARIO
End Sub

Sub DoOtherStuff
    'Do whatever should be done if the user is not DARIO
End Sub
```